# Submitting CSV via POST request - Post Coming Through Empty (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, post

I'm trying to read a CSV from a file and submit it via a POST request. For some reason no data is being sent in the request. Can anyone see what is going wrong in my code?

```
    FileStream rdr = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] inData = new byte[rdr.Length];
    rdr.Read(inData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(rdr.Length));

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.KeepAlive = false;
    req.ContentType = GetContentType(path);
    req.Method = "POST"; 
    req.ContentLength = rdr.Length;
    req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

    Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();

    reqStream.Write(inData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(rdr.Length));

    Stream dataStream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    responseFromServer = responseFromServer + reader.ReadToEnd();

    rdr.Close();
    reqStream.Close();
```

Comment: I think that troubles at server side.

Comment: Try closing the request stream first and then the reader. The writing is buffered as requested, it might kill it before being committed, who knows.

Comment: Ignore the above.How are you determining or tell that no data is transmitted?

Comment: The receiving party is saying the request is empty.

Comment: @Mircea Ion I tried closing the stream before the reason and had the same result. I am thinking maybe the issue is with the receiving party.

Comment: I changed my post cause I realized that's not the problem but you may have missed it. However how are you determining or tell that no data is transmitted?

Comment: I determined that the CSV data needed to be submitted as a variable's value. The third party I'm POSTing to could have mentioned that up front. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that the CSV data needed to be submitted as a variable's value. The third party I'm POSTing to could have mentioned that up front. Thanks for your help.